# Replace 0 with Blank in SAP CRM Web UI

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I have AET-filed (Type: `INT`) on Web UI. 
The field name is `Duration`.
At the moment, I want to realize the logic:
If `Duration` value is 0, then don't show it in my field else show the value.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to put some more details into your question? It is currently unclear what problem exactly you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Use IS INITIAL, that parameter automatically matches the type you are comparing with. If you compare with I then INITIAL is 0, if C then ' ', if DATS then '00000000'.

```
IF <variable> IS INITIAL.

ENDIF.
```